# Using with a RegEx in PowerShell to replace everything from the beginning of the string up to the first comma only with whatever I want

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this string:

```
CN=Salaried_Emplyees,OU=Migration,OU=Groups
```

and need a regex to replace everything from the beginning of the string up to the first comma **only** with whatever I want, ie change to:

```
CN=Anything,OU=Migration,OU=Groups
```

However every regex I try ends up matching to the last comma rather than stopping after the first one.

An example of what I've tried:

```
"CN=Salaried_Emplyees,OU=Migration,OU=Groups" -replace "^CN=.*,", "Anything"
```

ends up as

```
AnythingOU=Groups
```

EDIT:

I'd like to modify this further now by not matching the CN= part so it will only match:

```
Salaried_Emplyees,
```

not

```
CN=Salaried_Emplyees,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"CN=Anything,OU=Migration,OU=Groups" -replace '^(.*?),','YOURTEXT'
```

replace everything up to first comma (including it), basically you need to use `*?` for regex to be lazy and not greedy

```
"CN=Anything,OU=Migration,OU=Groups" -replace '(CN=)(.*?),','$1YOURTEXT,'
```

Comment: fantastic! it worked. Can you explain how please? as I tried lots of different ways. I think it's he brackets that made the difference

Comment: but generally speaking that's not very nice of you to do that @Mucker

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a different way,

```
$string = "CN=Salaried_Emplyees,OU=Migration,OU=Groups"
$string
$Newstring = $string -replace "^[^,]+", "CN=Anything"
$Newstring
```

- The `^` anchors at begin
- the `[^,]+`  is a negated characcter class matching everything but a comma
- the `+` means at least one of the previous.

Sample output

```
> Q:\Test\2017-03\SO_42543257.ps1
CN=Salaried_Emplyees,OU=Migration,OU=Groups
CN=Anything,OU=Migration,OU=Groups
```